# Why is kable() / column_spec() highlighting some but not all specified values?

Tags: r, dplyr, kable

Am using `kable()` to produce simple report. I want all final column values less than 15 to be highlighted:

```
question_results <- dplyr::data_frame ('\\#'=c(1:15), 'Pre-Test Avg.'=c(10, 60, 20, 30, 30, 20, 0, 30, 50, 0, 10, 30, 20, 40, 30), 'Post-Test Avg.'=c(87.5, 100, 100, 37.5, 75, 75, 87.5, 87.5, 62.5, 12.5, 87.5, 100, 62.5, 50, 100))

question_results$'$\\Delta$' <- question_results$'Post-Test Avg.' - question_results$'Pre-Test Avg.'

kable(question_results, align = "cccc", caption = "Question Data", format="latex", position = "h!", escape = FALSE) %>%
  row_spec(0,bold=TRUE) %>% 
  column_spec(4, background = ifelse(question_results$'$\\Delta$' > 15, "white", "yellow")) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped")) %>%
footnote(general = c("$\\\\Delta$ denotes simple change in value: Post-Test Score minus Pre-Test Score."), escape = FALSE, footnote_as_chunk = TRUE, threeparttable = TRUE)
```

Works great, except that the `12.5` on row 9 should also be highlighted. What am I missing??

Thanks in advance for any help.
[image]

Comment: I believe this is because you have `kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"))` in addition to coloring the cells. Then the striped rows will all have gray cell color. Does it work if you remove the striped option?

Comment: @Ben--yes! Very astute, sir! If you care to write this up--that striping will override background color edit--then I'd be happy to accept it as the solution. Thank you

Comment: Glad it was helpful. This also may be related to this [github issue](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/738).